# Getting a list of objects which implement an interface from a list of objects that might implement that interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I want to return a list of all of the GameObjects instances which are of a certain child class or use a certain interface within a list of GameObjects.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a list of all of the game objects of type T within allGameObjects
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static public List<T> AllTypeInList<T>(List<GameObjects> allGameObjects)
    {
        //Create return list
        List<T> returnList = new List<T>();

        foreach (GameObjects g in allGameObjects)
        {
            if (g is T)
            {
                returnList.Add( g );
            }
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```

As far as I can tell this should work logically, since the program will never try to add g to returnList unless it's of type T, but it won't compile. If I wasn't using a generic, int for example, I would just do Add( (int)g ), but that doesn't work here.

Comment: return allGameObjects.OfType<T>().ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the casted `g` once you know it implements `T`:

```
if (g is T castedG)
{
    returnList.Add( castedG );
}
```

But for production code use the existing `OfType<T>()` as suggested by @hans-passant

Oh and next time post the error you were getting please.

---

**Additional info**

You can trick the compiler to let you cast g directly if you type it as `object`:

```
returnList.Add( (T)(object)g );
```

That seems so wrong, but also basically [what LINQ uses](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1026).